# How to look for same columns from one dataframe in other dataframe pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have one dataframe like this,

```
tabla_aciertos= {'Numeros_acertados' : [5,5,5,4,4,3,4,2,3,3,1,2,2],'Estrellas_acertadas': [2,1,0,2,1,2,0,2,1,0,2,1,0]}
categorias = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
categoria_de_premios = pd.DataFrame (tabla_aciertos,index = [categorias] )
categoria_de_premios
```

```
   Numeros_acertados  Estrellas_acertadas
1                   5                    2
2                   5                    1
3                   5                    0
4                   4                    2
5                   4                    1
6                   3                    2
7                   4                    0
8                   2                    2
9                   3                    1
10                  3                    0
11                  1                    2
12                  2                    1
13                  2                    0
```

and another df :

```
sorteos_anteriores.iloc[:,:]

    uno dos tres    cuatro  cinco   Estrella1   Estrella2   bolas_Acertadas estrellas_Acertadas
Fecha                                   
2020-10-13  5   14  38  41  46  1   10  0   1
2020-09-10  11  15  35  41  50  5   8   1   0
2020-06-10  4   21  36  41  47  9   11  0   0
2020-02-10  6   12  15  40  45  3   9   0   0
2020-09-29  4   14  16  41  44  11  12  0   1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2004-12-03  15  24  28  44  47  4   5   0   0
2004-05-03  4   7   33  37  39  1   5   0   1
2004-02-27  14  18  19  31  37  4   5   0   0
2004-02-20  7   13  39  47  50  2   5   1   0
2004-02-13  16  29  32  36  41  7   9   0   0
1363 rows × 9 columns
```

Now I need to see in each and every row of the df "sorteos_anteriores" is in one of the all row from the first df, "tabla_aciertos" .

Let me give you one example,

Inmagine in "sorteos_anteriores" you have in:
`2019-11-2   in the column "bolas_Acertadas"= 5 and "estrellas_Acertadas= 1"`. Now you go to fist table, "tabla_aciertos" and you find that in `(index 2 = "Numeros_acertados" = 5 and Estrellas_acertadas=1)` . You have won a second (index=2) class prize. You should create a new column "Prize" in "sorteos_anteriores" and in each row write a number `from 1 to 13`  if you have some kind of prize of `0 or Nan` if you not.

I have try :

```
sorteos_anteriores ['categorias']  = sorteos_anteriores(sorteos_anteriores.loc[:,'bolas_Acertadas':'estrellas_Acertadas'] == tabla_premios.iloc[ : ,0:2])
```

Also with where and merge, but nothing works.

Thanks for your help.

**Thanks to Cuina Max I could do it.**

[answer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhuDi.png)

Comment: Why the merge didn't work? Using `how=outer` should work, filling up with NAs the rows that doesn't match `categoria_de_premios`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# supposing that the indexes, starting from one, correspond to the the premiums
categoria_de_premios['Categoria'] = df.index

# Merge using pd.merge and the appropriate arguments
sorteos_anteriores = (sorteos_anteriores.merge(
    categoria_de_premios,
    how='outer',
    left_on=['bolas_Acertadas','estrellas_Acertadas'],
    right_on=['Numeros_acertados', 'Estrellas_acertadas']
)).drop(columns=['Numeros_acertados', 'Estrellas_acertadas'])
```

Comment: You can use `.index` to convert index to a column in case the index is not sorted numerically.

Comment: Yes, @Ehsan, you're absolutely right. It's also simpler. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Although the only thing I changed was HOW= "inner". Thanks.